# How to initialize unordered_map directly with fixed element?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I want to initialize one `unordered_map` with fixed element 100. And the `keys` are from `0` to `100`, all values of those keys are `0`

```
using HashMap = unordered_map < int, int > ;

HashMap map;
for (int idx = 0; idx < 100; ++idx) {
    map[idx] = 0;
}
```

**Question 1:**

Is there any directly way to do that like the following codes in `python`?

```
d = {x: x % 2 == 0 for x in range(1, 11)}
```

**Question 2:**

With initialization codes above, I think all elements are sorted in ascending order, but the results are:

[image]

Why the first element is `8` and the second element is `64`, all left elements are in ascending order?

Comment: There's a reason unordered_maps are called **unordered** maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is not quite so pretty as the Python expression, but it should do the trick.

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iterator>
   #include <unordered_map>

   int main() {
       std::unordered_map<int, bool> m;
       int i = -1;
       std::generate_n(std::inserter(m, m.begin()),
                       10,
                       [&i](){
                                ++i;
                                return std::make_pair(i, i % 2 == 0);
      });
      for (auto const &p: m)
          std::cout << '<' << p.first << ", " << p.second << ">\n";
      return 0;
   }
   ```

   Live on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/tORFcj)
2. There is a reason unordered maps are called **unordered** maps. Since they are implemented as hash maps, the keys are not in any predictable order. Using an std::unordered_map for a dense collection of integer keys is probably not the most efficient solution to any problem, particularly if you expect to be able to extract the keys in order.

Answer (score 0):

1. consider `boost::irange`
2. the internal data structure for unordered map is [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which does not always hold key order during hashing.

Comment: The internal data structure for an unordered map is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (or similar); not a tree.

Comment: @Mankarse Oh, thanking for correction. I took it for ordered-map.